# SQL Query help requested

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am trying to use the following query

```vb
Dim sqlQry As String = "SELECT * FROM tblTest where Name=@NM and Rank=@RN"
```

Then I fill my dataadapter by

```
Dim dAdt As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQry, conStr)
```

But do not know where to put the parameters that I have set after where clause.

Comment: What does this question have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: That is where i want to use it

Comment: But that's not relevant to the question. The question would be the same whether you wanted to use it in ASP.NET or in a Windows Service.

Comment: `@Furqan` does your issue solved? or do you need any further help on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the parameters like this:

```
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()

' Create the SelectCommand.
Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblTest where Name=@NM and Rank=@RN", connection)

' Add the parameters for the SelectCommand.
command.Parameters.Add("@NM", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15)
command.Parameters.Add("@RN", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15)

adapter.SelectCommand = command
```

Check this [MSDN Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx#Y400)

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter

```
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@RN";
    param.Value         = inputCity;
```

Then add the param to your Sql Command.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: This doesn't show how the command is used with the data adaptor

Comment: If a user is unwilling to intelligently look at the answer and make an attempt to understand it then that is a problem they make for themselves. This was a quick 2 minutes answer because that's about how much research it takes to figure out the answer. If you want a tutorial then go read a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you need to create an instance of an SqlCommand and use your sqlQry with that. Then use SqlCommand.Parameters.Add() or SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue() to add your parameters. Initialize your SqlDataAdapter with the SqlCommand instead of the String you've created.

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(conStr)        
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqlQry, connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@NM", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value="Your Value"
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RN", "Your Value")
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    adapter.Fill(dataSet)
    Return dataSet
End Using
```